# Creating a Vertical UIPageControl

Tags: ios4, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

Anyone have an idea how to create a vertical UIPageControl? I have a UIScrollView with pagination enabled and I would like to have the UIPageControl sit on the side and appear vertically instead of horizontally.

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can apply a rotation transformation to the UIPageControl.

```
pageControl.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
```

**Swift 3.0**

```
let angle = CGFloat(M_PI_2)
pageControl.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: angle)
```

**Swift 4.0**

```
let angle = CGFloat.pi/2
    pageControl.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: angle)
```

Answer (score 6):

Update for Swift 3.1

```
pageControl.transform = pageControl.transform.rotated(by: .pi/2)
```

Answer (score 1):

iOS 16 and later versions support the use of the [direction](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipagecontrol/3930362-direction)

```
pageControl.direction = .topToBottom
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UICollectionView` with paging enabled and vertical scroll. This handles the vertical pagination automatically.

Answer (score 0):

page control has subviews, which must be rotated to make vertical dots

```
//create page control

    private let pageControl: UIPageControl = {
    let pageControl = UIPageControl()
    pageControl.numberOfPages = 3
    return pageControl
}()

//add page control as a subview to container UIView

override func viewDidLoad() {
     pageViewContainer.addSubview(pageControl)
}

//rotate it vertically

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    pageControl.frame = pageViewContainer.bounds
    pageControl.subviews.last?.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi/2)
    pageControl.subviews.first?.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi/2)
}
```