# How can I reduce the size of iOS view Paging range?

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

Recently, I made a project which needs to use UIPageViewController.

First, I made one UIPageVC and two normal UIVCs.(VC1, VC2)

So two normal VCs are controlled by the UIPageVC.

And then, I complete the vertical view paging successfully (not page curl mode, just scroll mode)

If I swipe down, than I can see the view change VC2 from VC1, and vice versa

Well, What i want to do is this.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fNQh.jpg) I set the VC1 size to small, so let a portion of the VC2 can be seen.

[2] If I swipe down(or up?) change the current view to the entire VC2

[3] and swipe returning, [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fNQh.jpg) state comes back

The following picture can help you to understand my explanation.

[image]

How can I make this?

IS there a any way by controlling Storyboard or code?

Plz let me know :)

Comment: I think you want a vertical page control instead of the standard horizontal page control

Just google around for it, this problem has been solved:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4927974/creating-a-vertical-uipagecontrol

Comment: Tthank you for your replying. I’m sorry but i haved already tried vertical paging successfully. The main focus in my question is that Top of the VC2 always can be seen if

Comment: i tried swipe up or down

Comment: this control will do what you want, download the example and try it: https://github.com/shkutkov/SMVerticalSegmentedControl

Comment: thank u for your kindness but is there any other way that made by swift? not objective c

Comment: @cslee92 - UIPageViewController is designed to show only one view at a time, so it is probably not the method you want. Do you have only the two views? Or do you need many views, each one showing a small portion of the next?

Comment: Actually, only two viewController. FirstVC is Scroll view which contains 4 views so i can swipe horizontal and i already implemented it. This FirstVC’s entire view size is smaller than ordinary VC. So I must show a small portion of SecondVC’s top

Comment: There is a reason i want to show top of SecondVC. SecondVC’s top portion is a small bar that contains barcode image. So if I siwpe down the view, FirstVC will be disappeared and Second VC’s small portion will be located on the top of the current view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this fairly easily using a normal `UIScrollView` instead of a `UIPageViewController`.

- Add `FirstVC` view to the scroll view
- constrain its top, leading and trailing to the scroll view
- constrain its width to the scroll view's width
- constrain its height to the scroll view's height ***minus*** the amount of VC2 you want visible

then

- add `SecondVC` view to the scroll view
- constrain its **top** to the **bottom** of FirstVC's view
- constrain its leading and trailing to the scroll view
- constrain its width to the scroll view's width
- constrain its height to the scroll view's **full** height
- constrain its bottom to the bottom of the scroll view

and enable paging on the scroll view.

You *can* do all of this in IB / Storyboard, but working with large scroll content can be cumbersome. Since you already have the two parts in separate view controllers (if I understood your description correctly), it's easier to set the constraints in code.

I've posted a full working example at: https://github.com/DonMag/YetAnotherScrollExample

Comment: wow amazing! This is exactly what I want!!! Thank you very much DonMag :) I'm very impressed by your kindness. Especially, making project your self and posting! Your advice was a big help.